# Best technique to make the photo look more realistic after editing it

Tags: photo-editing

What are some things to do to make a portrait photography look more genuine and realostic after editing it in Photoshop or Nikon Color ex?

Comment: photo editing can mean a lot of things. I think you will be likely to get more useful answers if you expand a little on what you mean by editing in this context. Are you adding or removing elements from the image? tweeking curves and levels? applying some filter or combination of filters?

Comment: This seems very, very broad. Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: What makes you feel the image doesn't look realistic? Is it too saturated, make it less saturated, etc. This may sound obvious, but perhaps it helps too look at over processed images of others and try to imagine what techniques were used to make them so. The same way you can look at images you consider well-processed and try to reverse engineer that process.

Comment: it may not look realistic to you as you are aware of the editing. someone else may look and think, it is fantastic! why don't you post an image as an example? you will receive proper constructive criticism and may also provide the answer you seek. otherwise, it is very difficult to provide an answer as we don't know the specifics of your question.

Comment: @kslstn good point.I shall try it

Comment: @Abdul N Quraishi I was looking for a technique meant for all photos. Like how we can use the her toning tool in Photoshop and later use it as a layer to give it more natural feel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way to bring back the natural look of an image after it's been overcooked in Photoshop is simply to blend in the unedited file at say 50%. This will give you more punch than the original, but will limit how unnatural it can look.

Comment: This looks like a good technique.

Comment: Its a perfect "neither fish nor fowl" recipe

Answer (score 1):

I think that the editing has to be made in a way that the image does not look faked. You must stop BEFORE it looks fake. Once it looks faked there is not much you can do to make it look natural again.

A good list of tutorials to learn to edit pictures in a natural way is "phlearn".

Answer (score 0):

I used to do a lot of editing of degrade material previously, both photo and video and have few ideas.

By 'degrade' i mean a kind of distructive image  transformation mostly found only in instagram images nowadays, because deficient chemical processes are not an issue anymore.

Open an 'broken' image in Photoshop,
Use curves with histograms display turned on.

From there you see the hystograms in natural shapes, formed similarly to normal distributions. If you dont know what it is, imagine a bell shape and looking at the histograms you can easily recognise them.

Learn how to distinguish those related to particular features in an image.

If you see a bell shape cut at one side with the low or high range - you would easily find a related region of clipped color. This kind of deficiency is destructive and is not easily recoverable. To recover it basically means replacing a part of the image.

If you find that all the bells in one of the R, G or B bands are located assymetrically, so there is a region totally clear of histogram blocks -  its a sign of a flattened data range by some editing operation or a deficient transcoding process.

What you can do about it, is moving the lower point of a curve right near the place on the histogram where the last bell shape is located, but not touching it.

Do it at the both sides of the curves - at the lower and at the higher range end.

If a the bell shaped heaps on the histogram are assymetric, try adding one intermediate point on curve and move.
You also need intermediate points if the colors are twisted, but try to keep the shape of the curve as simple as possible. The less transformation is applied overall -the better as a general rule.

What you can achieve is data ranges exposed more correctly for further editing.

One important thing when you repair an image or improving the data ranges for further processing is white ballance. You should watch for white objects and match their color with that of the implied color temperature of the illumination to which it is subjected.

Another important thing to watch for is skintone, if there is a human portrayed.

Of course there could be a green face portrayed, but you should calculate the conditions cintributing to that.
Is it the green whall which spills the color, or is it just an alien from another planet.

Or was it just a favorite instagram button?